# android.view.InflateException when launch on Android 5.0

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I have an android project. After compile and install on Android 4.0, it can works normally. But when install it on Android 5.0 and launch it, exception is thrown such as "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar". 
Is there any change on between Android 5.0 and before version?
Below is the error log

```
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827): Process: com.example.sbp_client_test, PID: 18827
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sbp_client_test/com.example.sbp_client_test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3489)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3561)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:367)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ListActivity.ensureList(ListActivity.java:312)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:263)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at com.example.sbp_client_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:167)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    ... 10 more
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    ... 28 more
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RtlSpacingHelper.setDirection(boolean)' on a null object reference
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged(Toolbar.java:296)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:13245)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:6032)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:4558)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4150)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:183)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:179)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:175)
01-05 18:40:40.540: E/AndroidRuntime(18827):    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace and the layout XML that is crashing.

Comment: @CommonsWare add logs above.